# Is it safe to grow vegetable bushes like Tomato and Chili Peppers on an Active Compost?

Tags: compost, tomatoes, chili

I have a 2 months old compost and there are still undecomposed greens in it, and I also have propagated some varieties of Capsicum cultivars & Tomato cultivars and they are getting bigger that they need to be transplanted to a larger containers. Will they grow on an active compost?

Comment: What do you mean by 'active' compost?

Comment: I should have explained that I know what active composting is, so I guess you might mean can you grow your plants in compost taken straight from your compost heap and used in pots, maybe?

Comment: What I mean is can I use compost on my pot while there are still fresh residue of Greens and the compost is still producing heat that might burn plant roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it. Unless you're composting using an 'active' method, that is, a hot method, any fungal spores, bacteria and other infective organisms will be present in the compost, and the fact you still have uncomposted green material means the heap is not ready for use. Even so, the best use for this material is on the garden, in open ground, not contained in pots.

Answer (score 1):

I use a cold method of composting and ONLY plant squashes and beans on my compost heap and thats it! It's a good use of useless land while i wait for the heap to break down although i do spread a layer of soil over the top to seal it in- well it looks nice and i don't have to feed or water any plants...worked last year-altough as advice to anyone don't do it on a chippings heap as the compost steals nitrogen to start breaking down and this stunts any plant grown in it! found that one out last year! only plant on ordinary garden compost heaps only- if in doubt use the advice above and don't do it if your not sure.